# Getting actual billable data size in ADX

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Looking at the the output of the following command , what column is representative of storage cost?

```
.show table <tablename> extents
```

So basically out of the following column what really is the size that's stored in the storage?

- OriginalSize
- ExtentSize
- CompressedSize
- IndexSize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the ExtentSize. The storage costs themselves are expected to be higher based on the recoverability setting (if its true the data will be kept for 14 additional days) and the metadata size which is stored on Azure storage as well.

Comment: so can we say that a single extent is bundled with its relevant metadata etc? Also, when we use the function estimate_data_size , does this take actual storage (extent size etc) that will be required into consideration?

Comment: Yes, that's correct from the table point of view but the metadata I was referring to is the database metadata which is not included in the ExtentSize (currently you do not have visibility to that size other than in the billing. The estimate_data_size() function estimates the table size as well, it is a different way to query for the table size.

Comment: so lets say I want to see the table size which is a more realistic representation from billing point of view , should I be adding up all the extent sizes (ExtentSize) for that table or should I be using the estimate_data_size function? What method do you recommend?

Comment: I recommend using the ExtentSize and adding to it the recoverability factor. This should give you a good estimate on the data size that was billed.

Comment: @Avnera Thank you. How would I "add the recoverability factor"?